# Why is Dash dcc.Dropdown() only returning the first 3 characters of a selected menu item to a callback function, rather than the entire value?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, callback, plotly-dash

The following code has been working for the last few weeks, however, just the other day a strange error started happening with the `dcc.Dropdown` menu seen below. Whenever a user selects a cocktail in the drop down menu, only the first 3 characters of the cocktail are returned to the callback function.

###### For example:

Given that `cocktail_names` is a properly formatted list (example: `['#106 Cocktail', '10 to 7', '1626', "1880's Americana", '19th Century']`).

- Case 1: If the user selects the choice `"1880's Americana"`, then the callback function returns the string `"188"`.
- Case 2: If the user selects the choice `"10 to 7"`, then the callback function returns the string `"10 "`.
- Case 3: If the user selects the choice `"#106 Cocktail'"`, then the callback function returns the string `"#10"`.

```
# import statements

import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Input, Output, State, dcc, html, callback
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import os
import pymysql.cursors

# connect dahs page to main app
dash.register_page(__name__, path='/Search')

# dropdown menu selection items
# cocktail_names is a list of cocktails, for example: ['#106 Cocktail', '10 to 7', '1626', "1880's Americana", '19th Century']
cocktail_names.sort()
options = [{'label': name, 'value': name} for name in cocktail_names]

# dash layout

layout = html.Div(children=[
# Cocktail Relay System
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(options=options,
        placeholder = "Select or Search for Cocktail",
        value= None,  # initial value displayed when page first loads
        clearable=False,
        searchable = True,
        style={"backgroundColor": "white", "color": "black"},
        id = "dropdown_cocktail"),
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.H1(id = "Cocktail_Output", style={'textAlign': 'center', 'margin-bottom':25, 'margin-top':25}),

])

# callback function

@callback(
Output("Cocktail_Output", component_property = "children"),
Input("dropdown_cocktail", component_property = "value")
)
def cocktail_output(user_input):
    output = ""
    if user_input is None:
        output = None
    else:
        return user_input
    return output
```

I have done some error testing by making sure the `cocktails_names` list contains all the labels in full correctly, which it does. Meaning this error must be coming from the communication between the dropdown menu and the callback function. If anyone has suggestions as to what may be causing this strange error please let me know.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the exact same code in a standard dash app, there must be something else..

Comment: Try checking the browser console to see what value is being sent to the output div. Is it really a truncated string, or is the div somehow not showing the full string?

Comment: It works very well with me without the problem you have. Try to print the coctail_name before you use it through your program